# simple sql query returns #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I've triple checked my syntax but I am completely stumped on this. All I'm doing is a simple SELECT WHERE mysql query but it's returning #1064 error. It has something to do with the second value check because when I remove it it works fine. Here's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM flo_chart WHERE im_key='357803040539808' AND key='b8cb8ebc11dbb641e2290c7ff954d6f8'
```

What is wrong with my key string that makes this query fail?!?!?!?!

Cheers!

Comment: are you sure your table name is table?

Comment: for the purposes of posting this to the internet I've changed my field and table names

Comment: Remove the semi-colon from the end.

Comment: ensure you dont paste errorneous SQL as it might divert the attention from the problem. Table is a keyword reserved in MYSQL.

Comment: wrap key inside backticks its a reserved word

Comment: Do you run this query using PHPMyAdmin or similar client application? If so, make sure that the client is not changing the queries. PHPMyAdmin adds the `LIMIT` to the end of the query. If this is the case, when you close your query with semicolon, the concatenated LIMIT keyword is treated as a new query (and the queries can not begin with the LIMIT keyword, so it is a syntax error). Try to remove the `;` at the end of the query, or use another client to query like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a reserved word for a field name so when it came to the sql query it failed

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table 
WHERE im_key='357803040539808' 
AND ym_key='b8cb8ebc11dbb641e2290c7ff954d6f8';
```

EDIT

After you posted up your **actual** query

```
SELECT * FROM flo_chart WHERE im_key='357803040539808' AND key='b8cb8ebc11dbb641e2290c7ff954d6f8'
```

you have used a reserved word `key`

Comment: this returns: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ym_key='b8cb8ebc11dbb641e2290c7ff954d6f8' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4

Comment: is question your whole query?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the keyword `KEY` as a column name. Try using some other names. (Ofcourse alter the column name)

```
SELECT * FROM flo_chart WHERE im_key='357803040539808' AND
key_New='b8cb8ebc11dbb641e2290c7ff954d6f8
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some reserved key words in mysql, in order to use that reserved word you need to  and use `backtick` to wrap the keyword.

**[key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html)** is reserved word in mysql

**Solution:**

```
SELECT * FROM flo_chart WHERE im_key='357803040539808' AND `key`='b8cb8ebc11dbb641e2290c7ff954d6f8'
                                                           ^^^^^
```